# C# set active form based on event, flashes form and sends to background - whats wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

i am writing an windows form (C#.NET) project which will run on a thinkpad tablet. I already wrote a custom textbox which triggers the tabtip keyboard on the device to help with onscreen input, however this is annoying since the user has to switch constantly between the different modes (numbers, text) and some other problems which i hope to eliminate by providing a custom form (keyboard) 
which simulates an onscreen keyboard.

**My Vision:**
On the Mainform the user selects a textbox by clicking into it, my keyboard form displays, is the active form and obtains the focus. The user can use the keyboard-form to send numbers/text into the previous selected textbox which is on the mainform. If he switches the focus back to the mainform it will bring it to the front and the keyboard (to the back).

**How I solved it:**
My Keyboard form is a Singleton which contains a method to register Textboxes which should trigger the previous mentioned behavior. The form contains a variable which will hold the current (or last) selected Textbox, to accomplish this I register the textbox's OnFocus event and set the variable as needed.

```
//part of the full solution
public TextBox CurrentControlInFocus
    {
        get { return _inFocusControl; }
        set
        {

            if (_inFocusControl != null && _inFocusControl != value)
            {
               //a new control is being selected 
               //so we should reset the color on the previous one 
               //to indicate to the user 
               //that it is not more the active control
                _inFocusControl.BackColor = DefaultColor;
            }
            // do nothing
            if (value == _inFocusControl) return;

            _inFocusControl = value;

            if (_inFocusControl != null)
            {
                //highlight the control to indicate 
               //to the user that this is the current 
               //active control
                _inFocusControl.BackColor = FocusColor;

                // activate the keyboard form.
                Application.OpenForms[Name].Activate();
            }
        }
    }
```

**My Issue:**
The keyboard is already displayed and sits behind the main form and i expected that the line

> Application.OpenForms[Name].Activate();

is going to bring it to the front and and make that the active form which is in focus, but what happens is that the form Flashes, comes to the front and then returns back into his previous z-order behind the mainform.

**Current *Undesired* Workaround:**
IF i change the TopMost property to yes on the keyboard form the code works as expected, however this doesnt meet my criteria that the keyboard should move back in the z-order if the mainform retrieves the focus again.

At the moment i am clueless what else i can try or what i am missing.

**[OPTIONAL]** since the textbox on the mainform is not in focus (since the keyboard form is) the caret does not display and animate, is there any easier solution than creating a custom textbox with overriden paint event and drawing the caret manually in that particular scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of @BoldAsLove 
I found a solution which works for me.

As he mentioned the MSDN article I was trying to switch focus out of the *GotFocus* event in a Textbox and it didn't work as expected.

However with a .BeginIvoke I was able to accomplish the focus switch from FormA to FormB.

```
 public TextBox CurrentControlInFocus
    {
        get { return _inFocusControl; }
        set
        {

            if (_inFocusControl != null && _inFocusControl != value)
            {
                _inFocusControl.BackColor = DefaultColor;

            }

            if (value == _inFocusControl) return;

            _inFocusControl = value;

            if (_inFocusControl != null)
            {
                _inFocusControl.BackColor = FocusColor;

                #region Important block
                var f = Application.OpenForms[Name] ?? Singleton;
                // just making sure both handles are created before using an invoke
                if (Handle != IntPtr.Zero && _inFocusControl.Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                    //call the invoke on the textbox control
                    _inFocusControl.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) (() => { 
                          f.Show(); //show the form 
                          // bring it to front
                          // it also should raise the event Activated 
                          f.Activate(); 
                    }));
                #endregion

            }
        }
    }
```

This is a pretty ugly way. I am pretty sure that usually a Button would trigger a scenario like this and I came across an exception / edge case. I needed to change focus to another form on a **GotFocus** event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    Application.OpenForms[Name].BringToFront()
```

edit:

My guess is that you can't give another form focus inside of a controls OnFocus event. This would be a easy thing to test, I would have done it but I don't have a C# env right now.

edit2:

From MSDN

> Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave, LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers.

You could try using a BeginInvoke to set the focus, I think it would look something like

```
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)new delegate()
                 { Application.OpenForms[Name].Activate(); });
```

Comment: [MSDN Activate brings it to the front.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx)  and the Form shows up, flashes twice and then goes back behind the MainForm. I did try BringToFront, Show, Focus and finally activate  but same behavior, the form does not stay in the front with the focus. I will try to reproduce the problem with a minimalistic form project.

Comment: I thought that it might be the focus in the Textbox causing the problem. I am actually using the "GotFocus" event to call then my OnScreenKeyboard Form. I will test your suggestion. Ok I found a work around for my problem based on your EDIT.